# Using \displaystyle in Equation environment

Tags: equations

I have an equation in `eqnarray` environment. The equation has a *sum* notation with subscript and superscript. The problem is that the subscript and superscript appear on sideways of the *sum* notation which looks pretty ugly. I came to know about `\displaystyle` but it can be used only with inline equation.

How can I use such a command with the `equation` or `eqnarray` environment.

Comment: \align doesn't work either. Just consider it an equation having only a _sum_ notation with subscript and superscript. Both the scripts are appearing on the lower and upper right sides of the _sum_ notation.

Comment: Actually, I want to place the \sum within a fraction but I don't like the way that it appears when compiled i.e. the N above it and the i = 1 below it appear as plain superscripts and subscripts respectively but I want them to be directly above and below the "sum of" sign on the top and bottom of the fraction. Normally, if you use \displaymath, then this works fine but I need the equation to be correctly numbered so I need to use it within the \equation environment.

Answer (score 13):

It may just be that you're using the environment incorrectly. This might be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  r    &= \sum_{i=k}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{m-n}{n-i} \\
  f(x) &= \frac{\sum_{i=k}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{m-n}{n-i}}{\binom{m}{n}} \\
  g(x) &= \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=k}^n\binom{n}{i}\binom{m-n}{n-i}}{\binom{m}{n}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the `align` (numbered) environment, as well as `\binom`. Numerator and denominator of fractions in display math mode are normally converted to `\textstyle`. Therefore, it requires a verbatim switch to `\displaystyle` if needed.

Comment: Yes. This is what I want. I have _sum_ in the denominator. However, if I use \displaystyle as above, I do get the _sum_ in right form, but I get some extra spacing before and after the equation.

Comment: @user846400 `eqnarray` requires two `&` symbols: `left hand side & = & right hand side`. But it's better *not* to use `eqnarray` at all, favoring `amsmath` environments.